# Sampling error in Lpc1769's Adc

Tags: adc, serial, lpc, graph

I am trying to sample sin wave using Lpc1769's Adc.
I am sampling signal using adc and send this data to pc using serial port (115200 baud rate). My sampling frequency is 1.5 kHz. When I sample 100 Hz signal, and then send this data to dac, dac output is 100 Hz signal. So this is good. But when I send this data to the pc the graph is wrong. 
Here is my screenshots.[image]

By the way, I am using zedgraph for drawing the signal in the pc side.
Also I checked the data missing condition. There is no data missing.

One interesting thing for me is, When I decrease the peak-to-peak value of the signal, I can see right graph in the pc side.

So Do you have any advices ? 
Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Top left graph looks like 10 kHz to me.

I think you may have your oscillator set incorrectly because what you think may be 75 Hz looks more like 25 kHz (top right picture).

I don't see 100 Hz anywhere. Bottom left (according to the time scale in milli seconds) looks like 50 kHz.

Are you sure you know what you are doing?